# MSI Installer Setup Project :Error 1001.An exception occured in the OnBeforeInstall Event handler

Tags: c#, exception, windows-installer, setup-project

I have a C# Windows Forms application and I have added a setup project to its solution to create MSI Installer.

I would like to provide some custom error messages to the end users when they're installing the software but it's showing

```
Error 1001. An exception occurred in the OnBeforeInstall Event Handler.
```

on rollback.

Could you please help me: how to implement custom error messages to the end user in this case?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of checking conditions in OnBeforeInstall Event Handler, try putting that code inside

**Install** Event Handler

and for getting out of installation process on failure of your custom condition/check do:

```
throw new InstallException("Custom Message.");
```

This will result in : **Error 1001.Custom Message.**

Another approach would be using **Orca** with your msi to edit the built-in messages.